# Using XSD file in WSDL

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, wcf, web-services

We have WSDL and XSD files given to us,

Now how can  we use that given XSD in WSDL, without adding manually all XSD elements in WSDL. do we have something by which we can directally import xsd file to WSDL?

Suggestion are welcome.

Comment: do you want to write a web service or a client to a web service?

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747196/wsdl-schemalocation-is-it-possible-to-import-a-xsd-into-a-wsdl-using-a-relat

Comment: I am writng web service which uses WSDL. @Demo I will check that answer

Comment: wsdl is automatically created for you. just create your asmx file.

Comment: as I said I am not creating WSDL, someone given me WSDL and XSD sepretaly so I need to use that XSD in given WSDL to run my web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD is the schema of your object you will be sending to you web service.
Use command line below to create a serialized object from you XSD file.
For example, lets assume your language is C#, and your web service is SendData()

xsd.exe -c -l:c# -n:XmlSerializationHowTo yourobject.xsd

This will create a class file called yourobject.cs
In you code, reference your web service, and call SendData(yourobject);
Note, you can also create sample xml from your xsd and vise versa.